# Swift UIButton Subclass and change color based on variable

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subclass

I'm using a subclass for my UIButton and it has a variable called isActive. I need to change the button border color based on that variable. This variable will change programmatically. Please help me with this.

```
@IBDesignable
class buttonCTAOutlineDark: UIButton {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    commonInit()
}

@IBInspectable var isActive: Bool {
    get {
        return self.isActive
    }
    set (active) {
        if active {
            commonInit(isActive: active)
        }
    }
}

func commonInit(isActive: Bool = false) {
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1

    if (isActive) {
        self.tintColor = ACTIVE_COLOR
        self.layer.borderColor = ACTIVE_COLOR.cgColor
    } else {
        self.tintColor = nil
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.69, green:0.72, blue:0.77, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use property observer didSet, willSet. whenever you will update properties value those method will call. have a look on it https://nshipster.com/swift-property-observers/

Comment: @hashHb `get {return self.isActive}` will be called recursively. So instead of that try `{return isActive}`. Also in `set (active)`, `commonInit` method will be called only when `active` is true. so you could try `set (active) { isActive = active;commonInit(isActive: active)}`

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend using those property observers at all, since it isn'r clear for the caller what sideeffects property changes can have. I would just create a method for it, that way, it is more clear for the caller that things can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `isActive` property is written incorrectly. It should not be a computed property in the first place. Currently, the getter will just cause infinite recursion and the setter doesn't actually set anything.

The `isActive` property should be a stored property with a `didSet` property observer:

```
@IBInspectable
var isActive: Bool {
    didSet {

    }
}
```

Inside `didSet`, you can just put the last part of `commonInit`. The first part of `commonInit` doesn't need to be run every time `isActive` changes. I recommend you to extract that as a method called `updateBorder`:

```
func updateBorder(isActive: Bool) {

    if (isActive) {
        self.tintColor = ACTIVE_COLOR
        self.layer.borderColor = ACTIVE_COLOR.cgColor
    } else {
        self.tintColor = nil
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.69, green:0.72, blue:0.77, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    }

}
```

And then in `didSet`, you can just call that:

```
updateBorder(isActive: isActive)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be observing `didSet` to update the `view`. In `Swift`, type names should start with Uppercase e.g `ButtonCTAOutlineDark`. Please see the fixed class,

```
@IBDesignable
class ButtonCTAOutlineDark: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    @IBInspectable var isActive: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.commonInit(isActive: self.isActive)
        }
    }

    func commonInit(isActive: Bool = false) {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1

        if (isActive) {
            self.tintColor = ACTIVE_COLOR
            self.layer.borderColor = ACTIVE_COLOR.cgColor
        } else {
            self.tintColor = nil
            self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.69, green:0.72, blue:0.77, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        }
    }
}
```